# How to bind methods in one interface to differenct SqlSessrions

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis

In my spring boot application, I need to connect to multiple data sources(I know it's an anti-pattern). So I've configured different datasources and corresponding SqlSessionFactories. With a MapperScannerConfigurer I can point to different packages. So for example, bind interfaces in package com.dat.dao1 to SqlSessionFactory1 and those in com.dat.dao2 to SqlSessionFactory2. I was wondering if there's a way to have this binding in method level so I can decide which method is backed by which SqlSessionFactory. Is there an annotation with which I can choose the SqlSessionFactory or even SqlSession?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported out of the box in mybatis. If you want to override this behaviour you would need to change how [MapperProxy](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/binding/MapperProxy.java) behaves. You can make its `invoke` method sensitive to some annotation and use appropriate `SqlSession`.

While this is rather simple the more effort is needed to make mybatis use your implementation. In order to use your implementation instead of existing `MapperProxy` you would need to change

1. `MapperProxyFactory` to create your class instead of `MapperProxy`
2. `MapperRegistry` to use you `MapperProxyFactory`
3. and `MapperScannerConfigurer` to use your `MapperRegistry`

because all these classes are hardcoded and are not configurable.

So it is much easier to use two separate `MapperScannerConfigurer` that scan different packages or that have different `annotationClass` configured.